# .Net T4 using TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor

Tags: dynamic, visual-studio-2012, t4

I am doing the following:

1. Defining a workflow in XML.
2. Transforming the workflow to objects using LINQ.
3. At runtime, creating a T4-based C# file based on #2.
4. Compiling and instantiating #3.

**NOTE:** all this has to occur on client machines, so there cannot be a dependency on Visual Studio.

I've got #1 and #2 figured out, but only part of #3. I can't figure out how to pass the results of the XML => object steps to the tt file.

My tt file:

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostSpecific="false" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#
#>
using System;

namespace RWT.Direct.Core.Public.Servers
{
    public partial class ServerClass
    {
        public void CanYouSeeMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this should be from a property");
        }
    }
}
```

Partial Class (normal .cs):

```
namespace RWT.Direct.Core.Public.Servers
{
    public partial class ServerClass : ServerTemplate
    {
        public string MyParameter;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
ServerClass sc = new ServerClass();
sc.MyParameter = "abc"; // set property
String pageContent = sc.TransformText();
Console.WriteLine(pageContent); // compile step goes here
```

In implementation, property will be of type List.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another option besides extending the generated template class:

Have a look at the `<#@ parameter #>` directive ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586944.aspx)). Using this directive t4 automatically generates a property for you that is accessible inside the template code:

```
<#@ template #>
<#@ parameter name="parameter" type="System.String" #>

// value of the parameter <#= this.parameter #>
```

You can set this property via the templating session when creating the template instance:

```
var instance = new Template(); // replace Template with your template's class name
instance.Sesion = new Dictionary<string, object>();
instance.Session.Add("parameter", "this should be from a property");
instance.Initialize();

var result = instance.TransformText();

// compile your result here
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in part from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43394/T4-Preprocessed-Text-Templates-in-Visual-Studio-20).